# WeasyPrint - Https certificate verify failed

Tags: python, weasyprint

I am using weasyprint on windows

Python script as below:

```
from weasyprint import HTML
HTML('https://localhost:82/page/').write_pdf('weasyprint.pdf')
```

**https** is SSL is local iis express
[image]

Error as below:

```
weasyprint.urls.URLFetchingError: URLError: <urlopen error [SSL:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:777)
```

As we are using iis express certificate for the website.
Is there a way to skip this error?

Comment: use a file-like object as parameter instead of the url string. You can then make the request using standard python url retrieval methods and specify not to do cert validation. You might also have to provide a [custom url fetcher](http://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#url-fetchers)

Answer (score 3):

You should Globally cancel the ssl verification

`import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context`

Then things will be solved!

Comment: I know this is old, but this could be a security vulnerability if you're fetching https externally right?

Comment: @LuisFHernandez,  If using external URL then yes.